# Restrict Microsoft app access to MS Graph emails for a single user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are building a service that is expected to use MS Graph to send out emails to customers on a regular basis. Mailbox for sending out emails is setup like `no-reply@contoso.com`.

I have configured an app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. And since this service will be running on the server side to send out emails only, without user interaction, I opted to using the `Application Permission` named `Mail.Send (admin only)`.

Such a setup requires `admin` consent. And my sys-admin is concerned that the app is requiring too much access that what it is intended to. He is right, as the requested permission will let the app/service send out emails as anyone in the organisation.

I know that I could use `Delegate Permission` option and get an `auth code` initially and let the service to continuously pickup a new access-token, based on refresh-token. I am not sure if this is idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, congrats for having an on-the-ball Admin. What they're concerned about is frankly why Graph requires Admin Consent, the application permission scopes are fairly broad.

The only way to narrow the scope to a single user is to use Delegated permissions. If you request `offline_access` as part of your scopes, this will include the `refresh_token` that you'll need to remain logged in.

One important note on this model, you may need to periodically re-authenticate. Certain events such as changing passwords will nullify your tokens and require a fresh login to get a new set. You should be sure to include a notification mechanism that alters someone if the app is unable to refresh it's token.

Comment: @marc-lafleur-msft: How long are the refresh_token valid for?

Comment: It was recently changed to `until-revoked`. You can read about the change [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2017/08/31/changes-to-the-token-lifetime-defaults-in-azure-ad/)